# Getting null object reference If i start 2nd activity before 3rd activity (No error if I move from 1st to 3rd directly)

Tags: java, android, json, web-services

I know its a common error , and i know lots of topics here were asking about the same error, but i tried alot of solutions and non works.
My application is like this:

1st activity is a sign in activity,
2nd is a menu to navigate where to go,
3rd is the customer's details.

I think i know where the problem is but i don't whats causing it

In the 2nd activity i am calling a function to get the customer id (the same function i am calling in the 3rd activity but without taking all the details i am only taking it's ID because i need it in other activities )

So result i am getting second time is always null , which is causing this error

so if i jump directly from 1st to 3rd app doesn't crash.

but (1st 2nd 3rd ) then the function will be called twice (even though i am storing data in a different object) and works only at the first time it's called

Hope i explained it well

now my code for 2nd activity:

```
public class AfterLogin extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new AsyncpkAbone().execute(SharedValues.AboneKod);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_after_login);


    }
    public void AboneBilgiPressed(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(AfterLogin.this, UserDetailsActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(i);


    }


    protected class AsyncpkAbone extends AsyncTask<String,Void,UserDetailsTable>
    {

        @Override
        protected UserDetailsTable doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            UserDetailsTable userDetail2=null;
            RestAPI api = new RestAPI();
            try {

                JSONObject jsonObj = api.GetUserDetails(params[0]);
                JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
                userDetail2 = parser.parseUserDetails(jsonObj);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("AsyncUserDetails", e.getMessage());

            }

            return userDetail2;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(UserDetailsTable result2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            SharedValues.AboneKod =result2.getAboneKod();
            SharedValues.pkAbone = result2.getPkAbone();

        }

    }
```

the Code for the 3rd activity (user details)

```
public class UserDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tvAdres, tvTelefon,tvpkAbone;
    String Adres;
    String WEBParola;
    String Tel1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_details);
        new AsyncUserDetails().execute(SharedValues.AboneKod);


        tvAdres = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_firstname);
        tvAdres.setTextIsSelectable(true);

        tvTelefon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_lastname);
        tvTelefon.setTextIsSelectable(true);

        tvpkAbone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_pkAbone);
        tvpkAbone.setTextIsSelectable(true);

        tvAdres.setText(Adres);
        tvTelefon.setText(Tel1);
        tvpkAbone.setText(String.valueOf( SharedValues.pkAbone));

    }

    protected class AsyncUserDetails extends AsyncTask<String,Void,UserDetailsTable>
    {

        @Override
        protected UserDetailsTable doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            UserDetailsTable userDetail=null;
            RestAPI api = new RestAPI();
            try {

                JSONObject jsonObj = api.GetUserDetails(params[0]);
                JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
                userDetail = parser.parseUserDetails(jsonObj);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("AsyncUserDetails", e.getMessage());

            }

            return userDetail;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(UserDetailsTable result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            tvAdres.setText(result.getAdres());
            tvTelefon.setText(result.getTelefon());

        }

    }
```

the data i get from the function is stored in a object of type (userdetails tables)

the code for the Userdetailstable is (might be needed)

```
package com.artyazilim.art;

public class UserDetailsTable {

    String Adres,Tel1,AboneKod,WEBParola;
    int pkAbone;
    public UserDetailsTable(String Adres, String Tel1, String AboneKod,
                            String WEBParola,int pkAbone) {
        super();
        this.Adres = Adres;
        this.Tel1 = Tel1;
        this.AboneKod = AboneKod;
        this.WEBParola = WEBParola;
        this.pkAbone = pkAbone;
    }

    public UserDetailsTable() {
        super();
        this.Adres = null;
        this.Tel1 = null;
        this.AboneKod = null;
        this.WEBParola = null;
        this.pkAbone = 0;
    }

    public String getAdres() {
        return Adres;
    }

    public void setAdres(String adres) {
        Adres = adres;
    }

    public String getTelefon() {
        return Tel1;
    }

    public void setTelefon(String telefon) {
        Tel1 = telefon;
    }

    public String getAboneKod() {
        return AboneKod;
    }

    public void setAboneKod(String aboneKod) {
        AboneKod = aboneKod;
    }

    public String getWEBParola() {
        return WEBParola;
    }

    public void setWEBParola(String WEBParola) {
        this.WEBParola = WEBParola;
    }

    public int getPkAbone() {
        return pkAbone;
    }

    public void setPkAbone(int pkAbone) {
        this.pkAbone = pkAbone;
    }
}
```

the function which i am calling in the both Async is this:

```
 public JSONObject GetUserDetails(String AboneKod) throws Exception {
        JSONObject result = null;
        JSONObject o = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject p = new JSONObject();
        o.put("interface","Service1");
        o.put("method", "GetUserDetails");
        p.put("AboneKod",mapObject(AboneKod));
        o.put("parameters", p);
        String s = o.toString();
        String r = load(s);
        result = new JSONObject(r);
        return result;
    }
```

and in the web service this is the GetUserDetails function:

```
public DataTable GetUserDetails(string AboneKod)
{       
    DataTable userDetailsTable = new DataTable();
    userDetailsTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Adres", typeof(String)));
    userDetailsTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Tel1", typeof(String)));
    userDetailsTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("pkAbone", typeof(String)));

    if (dbConnection.State.ToString() == "Closed")
    {
        dbConnection.Open();
    }

    string query = "SELECT Adres,Tel1,pkAbone FROM r_Abone WHERE AboneKod='" + AboneKod + "';";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, dbConnection);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            userDetailsTable.Rows.Add(reader["Adres"], reader["Tel1"], reader["pkAbone"]);
        }
    }

    reader.Close();
    dbConnection.Close();
    return userDetailsTable;

}
```

the error i am getting when going from 2nd to 3rd is

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String com.artyazilim.art.UserDetailsTable.getAdres()' on a
>   null object reference
>
> 10-30 05:33:13.410 24881-24881/com.artyazilim.art E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at
>   com.artyazilim.art.UserDetailsActivity$AsyncUserDetails.onPostExecute(UserDetailsActivity.java:74)
>
> 10-30 05:33:13.410 24881-24881/com.artyazilim.art E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at
>   com.artyazilim.art.UserDetailsActivity$AsyncUserDetails.onPostExecute(UserDetailsActivity.java:47)
>   10

i know it seems like a duplicate and I know the rules search before ask,I have spent lots of time trying other's solutions but the reason i might didn't find  the answer else where is because i don't know whats is actually causing this error so not knowing what to search for.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you narrow your code to provide only the relevant one ?

Comment: check if(result.getAdres() != null) before tvAdres.setText(result.getAdres());

Comment: @X.L.Ant Sure sorry i forgot to

Comment: @activesince93 I tried that still same error coming

Comment: if still you are getting NullPointerException then you are getting "result" null.

Comment: But it should't come null because if i call it first time it is not null but the second time it comes null
i'll add the function which is responsible for the result 
thanks alot for your help @activesince93

Comment: I have made a -Turn around- and just made a copy of the function and the userdetailsTable , changed the name of them and it works.., but it's not the solution since i don't know why the second object of type userdetailstable is always null, i will use this turn around till someone answer this question ... thanks alot for your help 
@activesince93

Comment: What is `SharedValues.AboneKod`?

Comment: @Rami it's just a static object (string) that i made in a class called sharedvalues Because i need this string to be accessed from all activities

Comment: In you second activity check if `result2.getAboneKod();` is returning a null object. I think this is why when you open the 3rd activity from the 2nd, you have the NullPointerException. Also its better to use Intents to pass data between activities instead of using a static class/object or at least use a [singleton](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/singleton_pattern.htm) class.

Comment: @Rami That solved it thanks alot :))
I was pushing a null value to the Abonekod and replacing the existing value.
Can you please put your answer separately so i can mark it as a solution ?
And i am using a static object because i only need this value and if i don't i will have to keep passing it between activities using intents  every time the user moves from activity to another.
any risks of using the static one ?
Anyone thanks alot for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you second activity check if `result2.getAboneKod();` is not returning a `null` object.

I think this is why when you open the 3rd activity from the 2nd, you have the `NullPointerException`.